# How to fix grey space of right and left side of webpage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I m using bootstrap 5 and using columns with it.
However, after doing there is black space on the right side of the screen and left side of the screen some content is disappearing as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkE0i.png)
Code:

```
<div id="skills">        
        <div id="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col align-self-center">
                        <img height="50%" width="50%" src="./images/frontend.png" alt="frontend img">
                        <h2>Frontend Development</h1>
                        <p>I use simple html, css, and js skills to create your frontend websites, with slight animations.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col align-self-center">
                        <img height="50%" width="50%" src="./images/full-stack-developer-icon.png" alt="fullstack img">
                        <h2>Full Stack Development</h2>
                        <p>I use the skills of frontend and backend combined to create your site. Recommened for most users.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col align-self-center">
                        <img height="50%" width="50%" src="./images/backend.png" alt="backend img">
                        <h2>Backend development</h2>
                        <p>I use Node.js and express.js to create your backend site. Requires frontend files.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
#skills p {
    font-family: "Dancing Script", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
}

#skills h2{
    font-family: "Solitreo", sans-serif;
}
```

What I tried:
setting margin didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra row that you don't need on your line 3

```
<div id="skills">        
    <div id="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col align-self-center">
                    <img height="50%" width="50%" src="./images/frontend.png" alt="frontend img">
                    <h2>Frontend Development</h2>
                    <p>I use simple html, css, and js skills to create your frontend websites, with slight animations.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col align-self-center">
                    <img height="50%" width="50%" src="./images/full-stack-developer-icon.png" alt="fullstack img">
                    <h2>Full Stack Development</h2>
                    <p>I use the skills of frontend and backend combined to create your site. Recommened for most users.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col align-self-center">
                    <img height="50%" width="50%" src="./images/backend.png" alt="backend img">
                    <h2>Backend development</h2>
                    <p>I use Node.js and express.js to create your backend site. Requires frontend files.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```